# Invalid operands of types on a scanf call

Tags: c

I am getting this error when I go to compile the program below, and I can't figure out why.

```
39:19: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [5]’ and ‘long long int’ to binary ‘operator&’
```

Here's the code.

```
int
main(void)
{
    long long d, p; 

    // Ask for number for the numbers of  days as long as input is between 28 and 31
    do  
    {
       printf("How many days are in your month?\n");
       scanf("%lld" &d);    // This is the line with the error
    }   
    while (d<28 || d>31);

    // Ask user for number of pennies for day 1 as long as input is not negative
    printf("How many Pennies do you have?\n");
    do
    {
        scanf("%lld", &p);    
    }
    while (p<0);

    //sum up the pennies
    int i;
    for (int i=0; i<=d-1; i++);
    {
        p = (p * 2);
    }

    // Format and print the total  (currently * instead of / for troube-shooting)
    double total;
    total = (p * 100);
    printf("Your ending amount it $%.2f.\n, total");        
}
```

Comment: I think it will be very confusing for readers in the future if you correct the error in your question. The answers would seem nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a comma in `scanf("%lld" &d);`. This is causing it to interpret the argument to `scanf` as the result of some characters BITANDed with a number.

Change it to:

```
scanf("%lld", &d);
```

Comment: @CalebLawrence, It happens. I must admit I can't recall ever leaving out a comma, but I did leave out a dot to access a member just yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

should be

```
scanf("%lld", &d); //not scanf("%lld" &d);
```

Comment: @CalebLawrence Not a problem. Here is how I troubleshoot issues like these. I start commenting out things until code compiles. Divide and conquer.